# Code Signing Error - Verify the value of the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

If i try to compile a IOS-Nativescript-App using cloud-service from sidekick, i get this error:

> (CLI) Code Signing Error: The file \"/tmp/builds/_/27e1345b5c089d99eb18995c590617489875f779/5.0.0/5.0.0/APPNAME/platforms/ios/APPNAME\APPNAME.entitlements\" could not be opened. Verify the value of the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS build setting for target \"APPNAME\" and build configuration \"Debug\" is correct and that the file exists on disk.
>
> [xcode-build] Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'

Im using nativescript on Windowssystem -  so i dont have xcode running locally...

My APPName.entitlement-File looks like the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>development</string>
    </dict>
```

Whats is your solution? :-)

Answer (score 52):

I also got this problem, but with a small twist. I think the reason it happened was the following:

1. I added capability "push notifications"
2. I deleted the entitlements file (moved it to trash), which is the file which was added when I added the "push notifications" capability

When I did this the error appeared after a while.

To fix it I went into `"Build Settings"` expanded the `"Signing"` tab and **removed** the line saying `"Code Signing Entitlements"`

This was done in Xcode 11.

Answer (score 24):

## Xcode 12

For me, this error happened because I have moved `.entitlements` file inside a group.

### To solve it:

1. Open `Settings` tab.
2. Go to `Signing` section.
3. Update value of `Code Signing Entitlements` to the `.entitlements` file current path.

### For example:

My `.entitlements` is located here:

[image]

So, the path should be as follows:

[image]

Comment: Im using nativescript on Windowssystem - so i dont have xcode running locally... so this is not the answer... because i dont have xcode...

Comment: This may be not the answer in your case, but this is the same logic you should follow to solve the issue. Good luck.

Comment: no, my question was using "nativescript on Windowssystem". its not the same logic, because on windows system i have no xcode....

Comment: You should update your question title so that others understand, it seems that many got here because of this title and as you see, my solution worked for him.

Comment: Also, notice that every answer above is about the Xcode solution!

Answer (score 7):

I know you've asked this 6 month ago, but maybe for someone this will be useful. I got this error message when in my entitlement were added Push Notifications but they were disabled in `Capabilities`. So I've just turned them on and everything started working. [image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please make sure Code Signing Entitlements

> Debug

and

> Release

also the same path as my screenshot

Answer (score 1):

My case was different cause I needed to change the Code Signing Identity in the BuildSettings All to Apple Development only.

This works for me on Xcode 12.5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My entitlements file ended with `.entitlement` instead of `.entitlement**s**`

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the Folder icon on the top left (Inside Project navigator) of Xcode
   [image]
2. Click on the project name which will open Project, Targets, General, Signing & Capabilities etc. Then click on the app name under Targets subheading.
3. Go to Build Settings tab
4. Scroll doen to Signing section and check the value of Code Signing Entitlements
5. Check the set value and file location. Correct working values are like this:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally dragged my Target folder inside another target, so is files changed location.