# Getting "entitlements could not be opened" error in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, code-signing-certificate, code-signing-entitlements

I'm getting the following error in Xcode:

[image]

When navigating to that folder, there indeed is no .entitlements file.
The thing is that I've never deleted that file nor have I forgotten to commit it to git, etc.
Project sits locally for weeks now.
Have added pushNotifications as a capability a few days back but haven't yet started to implement it. Just stumbled over this error now as I was trying to get started.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58821534/1987726) is the solution?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner: Thanks, that did the trick. Just weird that it happened in the first place. Never deleted the entitlements file it claims is gone. Hm...